# How do I tell headless chrome to make a screenshot with auto height?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, google-chrome-headless

I can take a screenshot of the page using headless chrome, while specifying the exact dimensions:

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot --window-size=1920,1080 https://example.com/
```

How to make the screenshot height automatically adjust to the actual content height? I need to get something like: `--window-size = 1920, auto`